# Sqoop - Get number of records retrieved by sqoop using java sqoop api

Tags: sqoop

I am calling sqoop using a java api, is there a way to get the job counter information or number records retrieved by sqoop job?

I am calling sqoop, using java api

```
final int ret = Sqoop.runTool(new String[] { ... });
```

Comment: I am looking for the same. Did you manage to resolve it ??

Comment: Used, yarn rest api to get the sqooped record.